# How to select rows containing non unique keys using a unique key?

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table;

```
----------------------------
| id |   pid   | operation |
----------------------------
| 5  |   12    |  pending  |
| 7  |   19    |  sent     |
| 8  |   12    |  replaced |
| 9  |   16    |  sent     |
| 12 |   12    |  closed   |
| 14 |   21    |  sent     |
----------------------------
```

`id` is a unique operation id, while `pid` is product id implying which operation is done for which product and therefore not unique. I need to list all operations of a product, using only an operation id.

I can do this by using a sub select like;

```
SELECT * FROM operations WHERE pid = (SELECT pid FROM operations WHERE id = 8);
```

This query lists the exact results I need, like;

```
----------------------------
| id |   pid   | operation |
----------------------------
| 5  |   12    |  pending  |
| 8  |   12    |  replaced |
| 12 |   12    |  closed   |
----------------------------
```

The question is; how can I do this without a sub select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join like this

```
SELECT a.* FROM operations a
join operations b on a.pid =b.pild
WHERE b.id=8
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT o1.* 
FROM operations o1 join
     operations o2 on o1.pid=o2.pid
WHERE o2.id = 8
```

Result:

```
id  pid operation
-------------------
5   12  pending
8   12  replaced
12  12  closed
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c53c/2)